# add object to array in for loop in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

We need to add responsive data to array and then we need to dispaly in html.We tried like this

```
var RequestAs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < RequestLength; i++)
{
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://183.82.0.221:2244/api/PostPets/GetCustomerDetails?ID=" + results.rows.item(i).PosterId + ""
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {

        var RequestA = response.data;
        $scope.RequestAs.push(RequestA);


    }, function myError(response) {
        alert(response);
        //console.log('ERR'+response.message);
    });
}
```

We tried in html like this

```
<div class="list" ng-hide="registered" ng-repeat="Reques in RequestAs">
    <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
        <a class="tab-item" href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
            {{Reques.CustName}}
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        {{Reques.Address}}
    </div>
</div>
```

We get data like this 
first loop

```
[
  {
    "CustName": "Pavan",
    "Address": "Hyd",
  }
]
```

Second

```
[
      {
        "CustName": "Naveen",
        "Address": "Eluru",
      }
    ]
```

Please guide to us.What worng in my code.We are stugglied last one day.

Comment: Whats the expected result?

Comment: @AdityaSingh thanks for reply.We need display two arrays data same time in Html. Please guide to us

Comment: try the suggested answer, if there is any problem then comment it

Comment: i not see where you assign something to `$scope.RequestAs`?

Comment: what you get in `response.data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting an array of customer detail, you have to get object from it, and every array having an object to index 0, try this

```
$scope.RequestAs.push(RequestA[0]);
```

Comment: thanks for reply.We tried as you said but no luck.Please guide to us